# Error: ImportError: cannot import name 'model_urls' from 'torchvision.models.vgg'

Tags: python, import, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I want to use the CRAFT text detector module. I installed all the required packages, but when I try to run the example code, I get

```
    ImportError: cannot import name 'model_urls' from 'torchvision.models.vgg'
```

I looked for solutions, but none of them worked.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72253737/642070, the software has changed. You could check package docs.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `model_urls` was removed because it was inconsistent across the code base
(see [this comment on Github](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/5836#issuecomment-1103702677)).

The authors recommend to update your code by removing the import for a non-existing module and getting model URL information for instance like this:

```
import pkgutil
import torchvision
from importlib import import_module

def get_torchvision_models():
    model_urls = dict()
    for _, name, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(torchvision.models.__path__):
        if ispkg:
            continue
        _zoo = import_module(f'torchvision.models.{name}')
        if hasattr(_zoo, 'model_urls'):
            _urls = getattr(_zoo, 'model_urls')
            model_urls.update(_urls)
    return model_urls
```

(from https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmcv/blob/fb486b96fd9932637a16f23a5dc60904c12bea7d/mmcv/runner/checkpoint.py#L108-L117)